# How to access to Animation Window private properties?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reflection

I want to access to private property `m_AnimEditor` of `Animation Window` (to be honest, I want to go even deeper, but it's not so important for now).

I'm getting the window:

```
EditorWindow[] allWindows = Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll<EditorWindow>();
EditorWindow animationWindow = null;
foreach (var editorWindow in allWindows) {
    if (editorWindow.titleContent.text.Equals("Animation")) {
        animationWindow = editorWindow;
        break;
    }
}
```

Now, I want to get `m_AnimEditor` property:

```
PropertyInfo animWindowPropInfo = animationWindow.GetType().GetProperty("m_AnimEditor", BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Instance);
```

But I'm getting `null`. See debug panel below:

[image]

I thought it was because `animationWindow` type maybe was `EditorWindow`, despite debugger was showing me `"(UnityEditor.AnimationWindow)"` and I tryed to convert the object:

```
Assembly assem = typeof(EditorWindow).Assembly;
Type type = assem.GetType("UnityEditor.AnimationWindow");
object castedObject = Convert.ChangeType(animationWindow, type);
PropertyInfo castedObjectPropInfo = castedObject.GetType().GetProperty("m_AnimEditor", BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Instance);
PropertyInfo[] castedObjectPropInfos = castedObject.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.GetField);
```

But the result was the same as earlier.
**BUT**, public property (`wantsMouseMove` for instance) I get easily. Problem only with private properties.

---

Maybe I do something wrong. What should I do to get the private property and then property of that property (object) too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try to use GetField ,this can get field info. I hope this can help you.

```
FieldInfo fieldInfo = animationWindow.GetType().GetField("m_AnimEditor", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, right. Why did I forget about FieldInfo?)) Thank you.

Comment: @SergeyMishin Maybe you can try  fieldInfo.GetValue().GetType().GetField()

Comment: Yeah) I remembered it. That's why I deleted that message)) Thank you again